# Power, Tower, and connection

Tags: tower, radio-control

Ok so lets say we have communications tower number 1 and comms tower number 2, if one were to get wiped out by a power surge, could the other sustain connection to the area?

Comment: “Communications towers” contain many different types of radio equipment that work in different ways. An accurate answer will depend on which radio service you're concerned with (cellular, amateur radio, business/public safety, point-to-point links for internet or private use...) Please consider [edit]ing your question to be more specific. (Do not use the answer box to respond.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends, If both towers are in the same place or the one tower that doesnt get cut out can reach past the other ones bounties, then yes it is possible. That is a very good question by the way.

Comment: Ok thank you that is very helpful.

Comment: No problem, Thank you for asking!